# Updating a listview inside Davigation Drawer

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listview

After thorough searching I still cannot find an answer.. So please help!!

I have a navigation drawer linked to an activity. The navigation drawer contains a listview inside it.
 I need to update this listview by a Button click which is inside a fragment.
How do I do it?

(I also have a same navigation drawer and listview for different activities. So the listview should be updated in all the activities.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to include the update list code inside a public static method inside the activity and call it from the fragment's button onclick method.

Comment: Tried it already..App keeps crashing

Comment: post the crash log..